# Kubernetes RBAC rule to limit listing to certain CustomResourceDefinitions

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-custom-resources, kubernetes-rbac

I have a lot of CRDs on my kubernetes cluster and I want to assign a role to developers so they can see only certain CRDs. However I couldn't find a way to limit it, I can only give access to all crd resources as follows:

```
- apiGroups: ["apiextensions.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["customresourcedefinitions"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

I m looking for a way to limit this with something like `resourceNames` but it doesn't work. Anyone knows a way to do it? or am I trying something impossible?

kubernetes version: 1.25

Comment: You can consider using validating admission webhooks  that validates whether the user should have access to a specific CRD